# Вывод из ArrayList в TextView

Tags: java, android, циклы, arraylist, textview

Есть несколько `ArrayList<String>`. Например, `arr1(txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4,txt5)` и `arr2(txt1,txt2,txt3)`. Также есть пять TextView, т.е. не больше,чем максимальный по размеру ArrayList :(`TextView1,TextView2,TextView3,TextView4,TextView5`). Как заполнить эти TextView из `arr1` в одном случае и `arr2` в другом, используя один алгоритм. Напрямую сетить через `ArrayList.get(0...4)` нельзя ибо приложение падает, т.к. `arr2.get(3)` уже не существует.

Comment: уточните один момент. Если в листе 3 элемента, то вам надо будет заполнить только 3 TextView или продублировать несколько элементов листа и заполнить все TextView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо хранить `TextView` также в списке. После этого бежать циклом по списку строк и эти строки передавать в соответствующий `TextView`. Примерно так:

```
List<String> strings = ...;

List<TextView> textViews = new ArrayList<>();
textViews.add(textView1);
textViews.add(textView2);
//etc

for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
    String str = strings.get(i);
    textViews.get(i).setTextt(str);
}
```

Comment: только лучше цикл  ограничить i < strings.size(). Т.к. автор уточнил, что листы имеют разный размер, а количество TextView равно максимальному размеру листа

Comment: Я это и имел в виду) опечатался)

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб , всё получилось! Спасибо!